# Winform - MVP - View Has Model Object -

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

A query about Passive View MVP.  I have has trouble finding an answer to this.  Most examples use simple types.

I have a View IInvoices that has a property that takes in a user defined object Invoices.

`IList<Invoices> ProformaList { get; set; }`

which is the Model.   As this is now in the View the View requires a `using` for the Model object.

To me this is "breaking the rules" of the pattern as now the using.

Is it ok to Reference Complex Object in the View that are Model types?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the question is whether it is okay for a view to know about the model it's supposed to display, then yes.

Comment: Every tutorial I read says the Model must have no link to the View.  The using in the View Interface breaks that. That is where I struggle to see why this is then allowed for created class objects.

Comment: `the Model must have no link to the View` - you realize that a link from model to view and a link from view to model are different links? Does your `Invoices` have a link to the view?

Comment: Model class has no knowledge of the View, it a simple POCO .
View does know the Model type Invoices (but everything is actioned in a presenter).

I think you have hit the main point.  
View can Link to the Model (for DataTypes and Binding) 
Model can not know anything about the View. 

If this is true i think my View is OK. 

Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386633/mvp-is-it-the-view-or-the-presenter-that-should-know-of-the-model)